# Not getting expected result in case of many to many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I am new to hibernate. I am trying to fetch result in a many to many mapping but not getting expected result.

I have two entities 1. Emp 2. Dept. Both are mapped to DB with many to many relationship.

Emp.java

```
@Entity
public class Emp {

    @Id 
    int empId;
    String empName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="emps")
    List<Dept> depts;

    public Emp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param empId
     * @param empName
     * @param depts
     */
    public Emp(int empId, String empName) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public List<Dept> getDepts() {
        return depts;
    }
    public void setDepts(List<Dept> depts) {
        this.depts = depts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emp [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + ", depts=" + depts + "]";
    }

}


Dept.java
@Entity
public class Dept {

    @Id 
    int deptId;
    String deptName;
    @ManyToMany()
    List<Emp> emps;

    public Dept() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param deptId
     * @param deptName
     * @param emps
     */
    public Dept(int deptId, String deptName) {
        super();
        this.deptId = deptId;
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }



    public int getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }
    public void setDeptId(int deptId) {
        this.deptId = deptId;
    }
    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }
    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    public List<Emp> getEmps() {
        return emps;
    }
    public void setEmps(List<Emp> emps) {
        this.emps = emps;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dept [deptId=" + deptId + ", deptName=" + deptName + ", emps=" + emps + "]";
    }   

}

App.java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Emp emp1 = new Emp(1, "X");
        Emp emp2 = new Emp(2, "Y");
        Emp emp3 = new Emp(3, "Z");
        List<Emp> empList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(emp1, emp2, emp3));

        Dept dept1 = new Dept(1, "Physics");
        Dept dept2 = new Dept(2, "Math");
        Dept dept3 = new Dept(3, "Chemistry");
        List<Dept> deptList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dept1, dept2, dept3));

        emp1.setDepts(deptList);
        dept2.setEmps(empList);

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Emp.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Dept.class).buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //Write business logic
        session.save(emp1);
        session.save(emp2);
        session.save(emp3);

        session.save(dept1);
        session.save(dept2);
        session.save(dept3);

        Emp e = session.get(Emp.class, 1);
        List<Dept> depts = e.getDepts();

        for(Dept d : depts)
            System.out.println(e.getEmpId()+" .. "+d.getDeptId()+" .. "+d.getDeptName());


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

In Configuration file: when I am specifying hbm2ddl.auto as 'create', it's giving me expected result as below: 
Emp details
1 .. 1 .. Physics
1 .. 2 .. Math
1 .. 3 .. Chemistry

but when I change it to 'update' and comment save operations I did in App.java, it's giving me below result.
1 .. 2 .. Math

Why is the mismatch in result. Please help.

Comment: Because that is how you definitly not map `ManyToMany`. Read [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the entity Emp add this

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE,
    CascadeType.DELETE
})
@JoinTable(name = "EMP_DEPT",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
)
private List<Dept> depts= new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want that the relation is bi-directional, add the following portion of code into Dept class:

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE,
    CascadeType.DELETE
})
@JoinTable(name = "EMP_DEPT",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
)
private List<Emp> emps= new ArrayList<>();
```

With this way of mapping you don't need to do insert into cross-table but simply setting on the entities(Empt e Dept in your case) the list associated.

Comment: One more query I have ..  in this case when I have to remove a row from table 'Emp', do I need to drop the table 'EMP_DEPT' first and then write delete query?